# Linode Munin Nodes

Tags: munin, linode

I have 3 servers in Linode. All of them are configured with private lan network. All 3 are able to ping each other. I have install a Munin master server in one of them and Munin node to all of them.

I open the port for the master node to accept port 4949. I have configure the master node to the other 2 slave nodes. I have also configure the slave nodes to allow the master node's ip address.

But in the Munin monitoring site, im only able to receive the local host data.
Is there something missing?

Comment: Is munin-node running on all hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The ports needs to be open on the slave nodes instead of the master node.